# Java for-loop and boolean array all returning true

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, boolean

Not the best title but I need help/explanation as to why my for-loop/boolean array isn't working the way I want it to.

```
for (int i = 0; i < zombies.length; i++) {
    displayZombies(panel, g, zombies); 
    if (zomCollision(runner, zombies, panel, g) == true) 
      eliminated[i] = true;
    if (!eliminated[i])
      displayZombies(panel, g, zombies); 
  }
```

Basically, my code is a simple game where the user controls a point(the runner) and there is a certain amount of zombies that are spawned in the game.  The user wins by intersecting/colliding with **all** the zombies in the game which are stored as points in the zombies array.

`displayZombies` does what is says; it creates the zombies and displays them

`zomCollision` returns true if one of the zombies and the runner collide.

`zombies` is the point array that stores the number of zombies there are.

The boolean array `eliminated` is set to `false` (set to number of zombies there are).

When my runner intersects with one of the zombies, the `eliminated` array at index `i` should be set to `false`, thus causing that `if`-statement to not show that zombie.  However, the problem that I am struggling with is that when my runner hits any zombie, they all disappear.  Is it the `for`-loop that is causing that or the logic? Any advice would help, thanks!

Comment: Your `zomCollision` takes all zombies as a parameter. Why not one, you're in the for loop, right? For all zombies, if there is a collision with any of them, the eliminated = true. Well, there you have it.

Comment: How does displayZombies know which ones to display by the way? Why is it called twice?

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying, I'll implement what you said and see if it works! And I was doing some trial and error with the displayZombies method to see if it would help lol.  Thank you though for the advice!

Comment: It is not possible to answer your question based on the posted code. The result of `if (zomCollision(runner, zombies, panel, g) == true) ` depends on 4 arguments, none of which are defined in the code posted.